# Vue.js loading single-file components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and want to use single-file components, but I don't understand the workflow.

For example, I have three components: `App`, `Grid` and `List`

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data () {
            return {
                message: 'Hello Vue!'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Grid.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="left"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'grid',
        data: function () {
            return {
                grid: 'some-data'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**List.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="right"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'list',
    data: function () {
        return {
            text: 'some-text'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './vue/App.vue'
import Grid from './vue/Grid.vue'
import PatternList from './vue/PatternList.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
});

new Vue({
    el: '#grid',
    render: h => h(Grid)
});

new Vue({
    el: '#right',
    render: h => h(PatternList)
});
```

It works but I hope this isn't the right way to create nested components.

Can anyone show the way it should be done? Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can register components using the [`Vue.component` method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './vue/App.vue'
import Grid from './vue/Grid.vue'
import PatternList from './vue/PatternList.vue'

Vue.component('grid', Grid);
Vue.component('pattern-list', PatternList);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

And then add them to the `App` template directly using their tag name:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <grid></grid>
    <pattern-list></pattern-list>
  </div>
</template>
```

This registers the components globally, meaning that any Vue instance can add those components to their templates without any additional setup.

---

You can also register components to a Vue instance, like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  components: {
    'grid': Grid,
    'pattern-list': PatternList
  }
});
```

Or within the `script` tag of a single-file component:

```
<script>
import Grid from './vue/Grid.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'grid': Grid,
    'pattern-list': PatternList
  }
});
</script>
```

This registers the components just to that Vue instance, meaning that those registered components will only be available to use within the template for that Vue instance. A child component would not have access to those registered components unless those components are also registered to the child Vue instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats what I was searching.

Comment: Very nice summary! The Vue documentation pages is not very good at explaining this and showing the content of each file. One thing I found confusing was that each component has a "name" value in the data() function but that name is not actually used anywhere. I thought that was the name of the tag or something, but I see you actually give the tag its name either when you globally import it with Vue.component or the local components config.

Comment: Great response, this is a beautiful example of how good a stack overflow answer can be.