# Where to import component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

New to Vue, working off a scaffolded project from the command line. Currently I have:

`index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home

from '../components/home'



Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
})
```

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  // default styles are here
}
</style>
```

And `home.vue`

```
<template>
    <chart-component></chart-component>
</template>
// rest of home
```

I am trying to create and import `chart-component.vue` to use inside `home.vue` but not sure where to import it at. I've tried adding it in `main.js` and `App.vue` unsuccessfully.

`chart-component.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Testing Chart Component</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'chart',
        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This seems like a simple problem but unsure how to solve it. My best guess was importing it inside `App.vue` and adding a `components { ChartComponent }` underneath the `name`. Second attempt was importing it into `main.js` and putting `ChartComponent` inside `components: { App, ChartComponent }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js loading single-file components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568323/vue-js-loading-single-file-components)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would rename your component to `ChartComponent` from `chart-component`, as the dash is not a supported character. Vue will properly convert the name to dashes as needed, but when you're searching your code for components, it helps to have consistent names.

anyway. for using a component, you need to import it and define it first

home.vue:

```
<template>
    <ChartComponent></ChartComponent>
</template>

<script>
import ChartComponent from './ChartComponent';

export default {
  components: {
    ChartComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Got it to work. Since I only need it locally inside the `home.vue` component I imported it inside there under data I added

```
components: {
    'chart-component': ChartComponent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing component becomes much easier in [Vue 3 script setup SFCs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#sfc-script-setup)

```
<script setup>
  import ChartComponent from './components/ChartComponent.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <ChartComponent />
</template>
```